# Limiting access to MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Assume we have a controller whose route is `Project/{ProjectID:int}/Page/{PageNumber:int}`
This controller handles projects, each of which has an int ID, and each project has 100 pages

So project 1, page 33 would be accessed via:

```
http://localhost/project/1/page/33
```

I know I can protect access to this controller using the Authorize attribute.  For example, only Authenticated users may access "project".

What are my options about protecting access to projects?  Eg, Bill has access to projects (1,2,3), so he could access the controller above, but how can I prevent him from accessing?

```
http://localhost/project/4/page/13
```

Comment: This can still be handled by the `AuthorizationAttribute`, however, that level of authorization might be best handled at domain level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strict controller level authorization, `AuthorizationAttribute` is the way to go, but for lower-level id authorization, I've found the best way is to simply query only for what is actually available to the user.

In otherwords, if a certain project is only available to a particular user(s) then you no doubt have a `User` (or similar) property on the the `Project` model (equating to a foreign key at the database level). Therefore, *use this*: when you're fetching the project based on the id, add a condition for the user as well:

```
var project = db.Projects.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id && HttpContext.Current.Identity.Name == m.User.Username)
if (project == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

In a sense, you don't need to restrict access as much as just only make it available in the first place to the proper user.

Comment: +1 for me this is the way to go. The authorisation problem being described is definitely more domain level than controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is better to use **Authorization Attribute** for this purpose.
But, if you find other approach you may implement something like:

```
  protected void Application_AuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string userName = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name; // Bill
     string page = Request.FilePath; //   project/4/page/    
     if !(AuthorizeUtil.CheckAccess(page, userName)
                   Context.RewritePath("/AccessDenied");     

    }
```

Comment: Does the OP have to guess what `AuthorizeUtil` does? Also `Request.FilePath` is not a reliable way of checking the path as it doesn't include the full path.